# how to use alphabets that use multiple unicode points in regex?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, internationalization

Context: The following expression are written for tamil language text

`'^[சிகு]'` is the intended expression for lines that starts with either `'சி' or 'கு'` just like how in English `'^[ab]'` matches lines that start with either `'a' or 'b'`

But since Unicode represents some of the eastern languages with multiple code points `'^[ச,ி,க,ு]'` (using the commas for clarity) `சி -> ச,ி` and `கு -> க,ு`

Running the expression over few words in python, gives the following results (you can see the full results [here](https://gist.github.com/vanangamudi/591e311d709f5d5d6672a34d09b510cc)).

*Note: expected results can be obtained by using this expression `'^(சி|கு)'` but this works for this specific case, but what if I want to write expressions to match `சிசிசிகுகுசிகு`? is there anyway to make the expression `'^[சிகு]+'` to match `சிசிசிகுகுசிகு`??*

[image: snapshot of the results]

For ease of use, I adding the textual samples here.

Expected:

```
குல்
குழை
குறை
சிலை
குறி
குரு
சிறை
குடி
குடை
குமை
சிதை
குலை
குளி
குவி
```

Matched:

```
கடி
கழி
கலி
கலை
கா
கோடு
குல்
சேர்
சரி
கை
கரை
சாய்
கடு
குழை
குறை
கோ
சுழி
```

[1](https://gist.github.com/vanangamudi/591e311d709f5d5d6672a34d09b510cc) https://gist.github.com/vanangamudi/591e311d709f5d5d6672a34d09b510cc

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm no expert on Unicode, but it may be you need to [**`normalize`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) it. Be aware: *"Even if two unicode strings are normalized and look the same to a human reader, if one has combining characters and the other doesn’t, they may not compare equal."*

Comment: Python 3.5
But I do not think this is python specific, it is the side effect of unicode's representation. For Tamil, unicode do not consider compound alphabets like சி கு as single units and that does completely against the mental of Tamil speaking people. I wonder what other languages faces such issues. My question is about how can I write expression such that I can overcome these problems.

Comment: On European languages we also had ligatures (especially in cursive), and accented characters could be encoded by two code points. Unicode has an annex about splitting characters, "glyphs", words, lines, and it is not so simple. In addition, it depends on language (not only the script), period of text (IIRC tamil texts from beginning 1900 used sometime other "ligatures") (and it depends on font). So not really a think regex could solve (and I would tend to use regex only for computer stuffs, not human generated text).

Comment: Character classes only match *code units*, you cannot make a character class match more, e.g. a whole code point. You will *have to* use a grouping construct here.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I think the tools like regex that interface with humans should match the mental model of their mother tongue. Unicode representation could have helped to design easier solution. But the regex engines must design in such a way that it follows the linguistic conventions of the language. But that is easier said that done. Especially when patterns and strings contain symbols from multiple languages.  Btw I am surprised to see someone from Europe to know Tamil ligatures.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, you're right. I am working on a software to help non tech savvy people to do corpus/computational linguistics. Regex in its current incarnation is complicated enough for them :)

Comment: BTW, I worked on localizing into Malayalam 10 years ago. It also has some crazy ligatures that no one could handle at that time.

Comment: @vanangamudi: regex is an old language, enhanced several times, but so it is ugly. I also think we need tools to do handle different languages, but as far i know, there are none really good, and I think it would be very different than regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Yes. Tamil and Malayalam are closely related. Though Tamil and Malayalam use different scripts, there has been attempts to reform ligatures in Tamil, but I think Malayalam keeps its old ligatures still. Can I ask how did you end up working on Malayalam?

Comment: @vanangamudi There were some 6 ligatures I could not handle. It was not a regex thing, I just needed to replace the multibyte chars with there wide char representations, so I had to convert the text into hex codes, search for the hex code chunks, replace... That was really ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Character classes in Python only match a single *code unit/point*, those that can be matched with `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXXXX` notations. [Character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) do not match *char sequences*. [Grouping constructs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) are meant to do that.

You have **multibyte characters** that contain several code units, and they cannot be re-written as single code points, hence you will always get the OR behavior between the characters inside a character class as you described: `[சிகு]` (seen by the regex engine as `[ச,ிக,ு]` will match one of the four chars defined in the class, not either of the two *character sequences*.

**To match character sequences**, like the code units in the multibyte characters, you will *have to use a grouping construct*:

```
சி|கு
(?:சி|கு)
(சி|கு)
```